# Crystal reports if else formula with time conditon

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I am trying to make a formulate to suppress a text field if the time from 2 datetime fields are 12:00. Crystal says that my formula has some error in it but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
if (CStr(Maximum({Command.StartTime}), "HH:mm") = "12:00" && CStr(Maximum({Command.EndTime}), "HH:mm") = "12:00")
then 
    0
else
    1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your suppression formula using crystal syntax, try:

```
ctime({Command.StartTime}) = ctime(12,0,0) and ctime({Command.EndTime}) = ctime(12,0,0)
```